# Indicate whether terminal is idle in tab header

Tags: gnome-terminal

Is there a way to visualize which terminal tabs are idle (the shell is the current program) and which are busy (e.g. a `wget` process is in the foreground)? I'd like to see when my long-running tasks are done.

This should also work transparently for ssh, so a tab with ssh running but bash being the foreground process in that ssh session should be shown as idle.